# ngtable filtering on nested json

Tags: json, angularjs, filter, nested, ngtable

With reference to [ngTable filtering on nested fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22524230/ngtable-filtering-on-nested-fields) the solution works fine however if I add new fields to client

```
[{
id: 1,
date: "20/03/2014",
no: "1",
client: {
fullname: "ABC Catering",
lastname:"test",
middlename :"test2"
}}]
```

Could you please let me know how i can add for filters for last name and middlename also?With the below html code if i input a filter in last name the same text appears in last name and middle name and vice versa

```
<td data-title="'Client'" filter="{ 'client': 'text' }">
        {{ user.client.fullname }}
    </td> 
<td data-title="'Client'" filter="{ 'client': 'text' }">
        {{ user.client.lastname }}
    </td> 
<td data-title="'Client'" filter="{ 'client': 'text' }">
        {{ user.client.middlename }}
    </td>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<td data-title="'Client'" filter="{ 'client.fullname': 'text' }">
        {{ user.client.fullname }}
    </td> 
<td data-title="'Client'" filter="{ 'client.lastname': 'text' }">
        {{ user.client.lastname }}
    </td> 
<td data-title="'Client'" filter="{ 'client.middlename': 'text' }">
        {{ user.client.middlename }}
</td>
```

Comment: Hi,Ofcourse I have tried that but then filter doesn't work at all.I have created a plunker here http://plnkr.co/edit/dO5jeYMolNV3u7blDrcz?p=catalogue