# AngularJS ng-table filter not working on nested fields

Tags: angularjs, sorting, filter

I have a problem with filter in ng-table AngularJS
when I use it, it's work for

> {{p.quantite}},
>   {{p.montant}}, {{p.date | date:'dd/MM/yyyy'}}

but not working for others

> {{p.produitEspece.produitFamille.libelle}},
>   {{p.produitEspece.libelle}},{{p.clientClient.libelle }}

**this my code:**

**show_vente.html**

```
                                          <div class="panel-body">
                                            <h5 class="over-title margin-bottom-15" data-ng-init="displayData()">Liste <span class="text-bold">des ventes</span></h5>
                                            <div>
                                                <table ng-table="tableParams"  show-filter="true" class="table table-striped">
                                                    <tr ng-repeat="p in $data">
                                                        <td title="'Famille'" filter="{ 'famille': 'text' }" > {{p.produitEspece.produitFamille.libelle}} </td>
                                                        <td title="'Produit'" filter="{ 'produit': 'text' }" > {{p.produitEspece.libelle}} </td>
                                                        <td title="'Quantité'" filter="{ 'quantite': 'text' }" >{{p.quantite}}</td>
                                                        <td title="'Montant'" filter="{ 'montant': 'text' }" >{{p.montant}}</td>
                                                        <td title="'Client'" filter="{ 'client': 'text' }" >{{p.clientClient.libelle }}</td>
                                                        <td title="'Date'" filter="{ 'date': 'text' }">{{p.date | date:'dd/MM/yyyy'}}</td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                </table>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
```

**venteController.js**

```
var tableData = [];
$scope.filter = {
    key: undefined,
    failed: undefined
};
$scope.tableParams = new ngTableParams({
    page: 1,
    count: 25,
},{
    dataset: tableData,
    total:tableData.length,
    getData : function($defer,params){
        $http.get(prod.url+'/vente/all').then(function(response) {
            tableData = response.data;

            tableData = params.filter() ? $filter('filter')(tableData, params.filter()) : tableData;
            $defer.resolve(tableData.slice((params.page() - 1) * params.count(), params.page() * params.count()));
            params.total(tableData.length);
        });
    }
})
```

also sorting work just for "montant" and "quantite" and not working for others

help please

thanks in advance

**Update**

I found the solution of my problem, I did create my own filter:

> filter="{ 'client': 'clienttext' }"

...

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="ng-table/filters/clienttext.html">
            <input type="text" name="filter-clienttext" ng-model="params.filter().clientClient.libelle" class="input-filter form-control"/>
        </script>
```

thanks :)

Comment: Can u create plunker with your data sample? Might this link will help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22524230/ngtable-filtering-on-nested-fields

Comment: user3249448 thank you, I did create my own filter :)